# Maximum value of maxRequestLength?

Tags: .net, iis-7, .net-4.0, maxrequestlength

If we are using IIS 7 and .Net Framework 4, what will be the maximum value of `maxRequestLength`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx) the default value is 4096 KB (4 MB).

UPDATE

As for the Maximum, since it is an int data type, then theoretically you can go up to 2,147,483,647. Also I wanted to make sure that you are aware that IIS 7 uses [maxAllowedContentLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28VS.90%29.aspx) for specifying [file upload size](http://jalukadev.blogspot.com/2009/11/from-iis6-maxrequestlength-to-iis7.html). By default it is set to 30000000 around 30MB and being an uint, it should theoretically allow a max of 4,294,967,295

Comment: He's asking for the max, not the default.

Comment: @Anthony thanks for the correction, I didn't notice the maximum part :)

Comment: Works great for IIS 8.0 as well if anyone runs into this!

Answer (score 92):

Maximum is 2097151, If you try set more error occurred.

Comment: I'm confused. The accepted answer is 2147483647, but this answer which is up-voted a lot more says 2097151. Which is it?

Comment: @Homer one is bytes and the other is kilobytes.  The value is specified in kB so you should use 2097151

Comment: @Homer the accepted answer only states the maximum value of the int type, where as IIS accepts this as the maximum value.

Answer (score 78):

These two settings worked for me to upload 1GB mp4 videos.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2097152" executionTimeout="240"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: If I am not wrong the maxRequestLength is in bytes. So the max value should be also 2147483648

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks a lot. This solution has resolved "System.OutOfMemory" issue.

Comment: @Sanchitos. The maxRequestLength is in KB.

Answer (score 7):

2,147,483,647 bytes, since the value is a signed integer (Int32). That's probably more than you'll need.

Comment: Equivalent of your value would be 2,097,152 (kB), which is *out of range* by 1. The maximum value is 2,097,151 (kB) i.e. 2,147,482,624 bytes.

Comment: Int32.MaxValue is 2,147,483,647. I didn't make this number up. If you doubt me, open up PowerShell and type `[int]::maxvalue` and see what you get.

Comment: Have you tried to set `maxRequestLength` to 2,147,483,647 or 2,097,152? You'll get a Configuration Error. That's why your answer is incorrect and I comment on it. `[int]::maxvalue` is not in an allowed range.

Comment: I've test maxRequestLength = 2147483648 and did not receive an error for IIS 7.5. Mark is correct. Perhaps it is different for IIS 6?

Answer (score 3):

Right value is below. (Tried)

```
maxRequestLength="2147483647" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
```