# Uploading file size over 4 MB in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, httpruntime

I am having trouble uploading a file size over 4 MB. I've tried adding

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="99999" />
```

to my Web.Config like many posts have suggested, but it just isn't working. Files under 4 MB work just fine, so I'm nearly certain I'm running into the 4 MB limit. Are there any settings in IIS that I might need to change?

Comment: We're going to need more information than "having trouble" and "just isn't working". Is this ASP.NET? IIS?

Comment: If you using IIS7, you might also need to check the "maxAllowedContentLength".  I think the default is 28MB, but it's possible this might have been changed...

Comment: Does the page have a large viewstate by any chance?

Comment: So I found that I had 2 web.config files in my project, and I was writing to the wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the value of maxrequestlength in the web.config:

[Maximum value of maxRequestLength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548305/maximum-value-of-maxrequestlength)

[Max Request Length](http://www.vishwamohan.com/post/2006/12/30/Error-SystemWebHttpException-Maximum-request-length-exceeded.aspx)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that then. So the question reads incorrectly then?

Comment: It reads differently than it did when I answered it...but no big deal. I think he was just incorporated what he'd already tried when he updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that code into your web.config file.

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="102400000000" 
 appRequestQueueLimit="100000" requestValidationMode="4.0"
 requestLengthDiskThreshold="10024000000000"/>
</system.web>
```

I think it will work