# Uploading files (up to 10Mb file size) with ASP.NET webAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I work on a VS2012 MVC4 project containing a Web API controller. This project will be published on an IIS server.

I need to allow users to upload files. The problem is a web API is limited up to 4MB maximum file size upload. I read (for example here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx) that we can extend this limitation by self hosting the web API (in this case file upload up to 2GB). I don't want self host my webAPI because I want to host it on my IIS web server so I think this is not suitable for my situation, right? So what can I do for uploading files bigger than 4MB?

If possible I search for an HTML5 solution (with drag'n drop).

So far none of the solutions I found allows me to accomplish this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Probably it was not clear but actually the blog URL is referring to IIS. You need to look for the following 2 settings in Web.config to increase the upload size:

Note `maxRequestLength` is in kbytes:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxQueryStringLength="" maxRequestLength="" maxUrlLength="" />
```

Note `maxAllowedContentLength` is in bytes:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="" maxQueryString="" maxUrl=""/>
```

Comment: See also this link about handling very large uploads:
http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/

Answer (score 1):

If you read it carefully, it says "ASP.NET has a maximum limit of 2G in terms of file size that you can upload." So basically when hosted in ASP.NET/IIS you will be able to receive files up to 2Gbs. What you have to do is change some default values in web.config.

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7154363/2517785

Answer (score -3):

**You can check this**

```
 int MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 10; //Size = 10 MB
if (postedFile.ContentLength > MaxContentLength)
{


}
```