# How do I configure MaxReceivedMessageSize in IIS hosted ASP.NET Web API (v1)?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

**EDIT:**  *I mis-diagnosed the exception.  It was from a WCF client call in my Web API controller, not from the Web API client.  Easy to fix by setting the maxReceivedMessageSize in my WCF client binding config.*

I am exceeding the maximum message size in Web API.  I can find how to configure it in WCF and in self-hosted Web API, but I can't find where to configure it in IIS hosted Web API.

Here is the exception:

```
CommunicationException The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize prop
erty on the appropriate binding element. Void HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowMaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Where can I access the the Web API binding settings so I can set the `MaxReceivedMessageSize`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post is confusing...your exception is related to WCF self host but your question is about IIS hosted application...they both are different...anyways here are the options for both hosts:

1. **Selfhost**: you can find the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` setting on `HttpSelfhostConfiguration`
2. **Webhost**: You need to make couple of settings in case of this. You can take a look at my reply here for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17324840/1184056

Comment: Actually, the exception is for a WCF client... I mis-diagnosed on my first pass of the production logs, but your comment in your answer got me turned in the right direction, so I just needed to set the maxReceivedMessageSize in the client binding config.