# The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded in Asp.net Web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am getting error while calling get method in web api.
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded.
How i can increase MaxReceivedMessageSize in web api.

Advance thanks for your help.

Comment: See maybe this [other SO question....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335442/how-do-i-configure-maxreceivedmessagesize-in-iis-hosted-asp-net-web-api-v1) - or you could **SEARCH** on this site.... there's already quite a few questions (and **answers!**) about this....

Comment: I tried but the result is "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element."