# Maximum request length exceeded in SQL Server while storing from ASP.NET framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am working on my own project. I need to save the files that are more than 4 MB in size. I just want to know the solution of this problem because by default in IIS Server it has 4 MB in a request filtering section under IIS.

I have also changed that by the reference of certain articles on web but did not find the exact solution of this problem. I think you geeks will understand my problem. And give me some valuable stuff.

I have not writing any code because this issue is not like that or something like that code error.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading file size over 4 MB in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154333/uploading-file-size-over-4-mb-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to upload the files in chunks (with Javascript), then the limit isn't a problem - assuming the chunks are smaller than 4 MB ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to upload first on disk

Then , if succesfull, put into sql server( assuming sql server and web hosting on the same pc)