# HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

Sorry StackOverflow, I know this is already asked and found lot of answers and i tried almost all and seems alright on config but throws exception so had to bring here.

I am limiting user to upload maximum 8 photos hince look like maximum request length exceeded.

I referenced from :

[Maximum value of maxRequestLength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548305/maximum-value-of-maxrequestlength)

[Maximum request length exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

and this is in my config file:

```
  <location path="MyHome.aspx">
 <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
 </system.web>
 </location>
 <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="Home.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
 </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Can someone help me on this, What am i doing wrong so my file are not uploading and throwing above exception?

Thank you and Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 4):

Your System.Web element seems to be under Location element , Make sure its under Configuration element.

Something like this :

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```