# Large dataset not being received from api when hosted in iis

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, http, iis, serialization

I have an ASP.NET api that responds with over 300k records.

When running from Visual Studio the data returns fine in chrome, but once hosted is IIS I receive a 200 but no data is returned from the api call

[image]

[image]

Logs on the server show data was retrieved just before the controller method exited

Is there a limit or issue with the serialization of records when hosted on IIS?

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Difficult to identify without code snippet used

Comment: You probably need to update the setting for maxRequestLength in web.config. 
Check this post out for the setting
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548305/maximum-value-of-maxrequestlength

Comment: Can you run a test that returns only several records to ensure it works?

Comment: I'm not firm with the IIS settings, but in general you can likely increase timeout and memory limit. For each of them there might exist several config-values which mean in detail distinct settings, so it might take some time to find all required variables to change.